# Have access to server installed on ubuntu from windows 10

Tags: 14.04, networking, windows-10

I use latest functionality from microsoft - install ubuntu on windows 10 and use it through Bash terminal.

It works, I installed php7, symfony - everything works. I run server on symfony, it works on 8000.

But, I want to test it and I can't, because http://127.0.0.1:8000 from my windows 10 does not work.

Perhaps I need use IP or virtual host to have access to server (on ubuntu) from windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your server over interface 0.0.0.0

> php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000

have you tested your server on Ubuntu side?

> telnet 127.0.0.0 8000

Best Regards!

Comment: Yes, I tested - on ubuntu it works. On windows - not.
I tried to use with 0.0.0.0 - no result.
Also I tried to use another port, e.g 99

Comment: Have you started as administrator in the windows cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is a special IP that's reserved for `localhost`. `localhost` effectively means "here": It refers to the machine you're on at the moment. If you call 127.0.0.1 on your Ubuntu machine, the IP refers to the Ubuntu machine. If you call 127.0.0.1 on your Windows machine, the IP refers to the Windows machine.

You need to bind your application to an IP that's reachable from other machines in your network. You can find that IP for example from the output of `ip addr show`:

```
....
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether d8:50:e6:5b:12:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.2.102/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 1777139sec preferred_lft 1777139sec
inet6 fe80::da50:e6ff:fe5b:1285/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
....
```

In the output, look for the network device that connects your machine to the network, in the example above "eth0" for the first ethernet device. After "inet" you see the IPv4 address, after "inet6" the IPv6 address. So, in this example, the machine is reachable under the IPs *192.168.2.102* and *fe80::da50:e6ff:fe5b:1285*.

To bind your application to the IP you've identified, you can use the command that LeoJava posted:

```
php bin/console server:run 192.168.2.102:8000
```

Now you should be able to reach your application from any machine in your network that can connect to that IP.

Comment: `ip addr show` - return SO_SNDBUF: Invalid argument.

`ifconfig -a` - return Can't open /proc/net/dev (missing file or directory).
I found that I need run bash from windows as admin. I did that - the same result

Comment: @yAnTar Are you trying to get the IP of your windows machine that way? You want to connect to your Ubuntu machine, so you need the IP of your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Reason, why I can't run `ifconfig` - microsoft did not support it right now. Will support on spring 2017 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/10/ifconfig-and-network-connection-enumeration-support-in-windows-10-insider-build-14965/)

@Henning Kockerbeck - I executed `ipconfig /all`, but I don't see Ubuntu machine and it's IP.

Comment: You need to execute `ip addr show` on the Ubuntu machine, *not* on the Windows machine.

Comment: I ran `ip addr show` and `ifconfig` on ubunt machine - it does not work (will work on next update windows 10 - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/10/ifconfig-and-network-connection-enumeration-support-in-windows-10-insider-build-14965/)

Comment: Please elaborate about your exact setup. I fail to see how the version of Windows on a completely different machine should influence whether `ip` or `ifconfig` works or not.

Comment: Because I use Bash shell for windows 10 (http://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/)

Comment: You use the Bash shell for Windows 10 on your Ubuntu machine? I'm sorry, but you've got me quite confused here.

Comment: Just to clarify: The windows machine and the Ubuntu machine *are* two different machines that are running at the same time, right? You should edit your question and explain more clearly about your setup, because it's hard to understand right now.

Comment: In post above - I add link - you can read, how microsoft implemented bash shell.