# Couldn't access rails app on Ubuntu VM on hyper-v

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v, ruby-on-rails

I have rails app on Ubuntu VM and I can access that app on localhost, the VM connected to the internet with Static IP When I ping the VM IP from another PC on the internet, the ping is working but when I try to access the rails app I can't.

Does anybody have the same problem or any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you start the Rails app? To which IP address did you bind the server? Maybe you bound the server to localhost or 127.0.0.1, which is not reachable from outside (see for example [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/852352/have-access-to-server-installed-on-ubuntu-from-windows-10/852403#852403)). That was in relation to a PHP app, but the principle would be the same.

Comment: I solved the problem by binding the VM IP 78.46.xx.xx with localhost inside  ubuntu hosts file like this:
78.46.xx.xx         localhost

Comment: Seems a bit laborious to me, compared with just starting the app on the correct IP. And it might prove problematic later, as something else might rely on the standard localhost = 127.0.0.1. So you might want to keep the change in the back of your mind, in case something strange occurs later ;)